# Does textbox save an all number text as a long or string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-management, variable-types

I have a brief discussion with my teammate regarding this. He says, if I enter a number in textbox, and try to use the value later on using textbox.text or val(textbox.text), I will not need to parse the value to integer. According to him, if the text attribute value is all number, you can directly get the value as integer, instead of string.

So, if I have `textBox1.Text = "12345"`, then next time, if I use, `intABC = textBox1.Text`, it will not throw an error. Is it right? Does C# or other .Net language does this implicit conversion? Also, will the code store `"12345"` as string or integer? And how much memory will this value take, 5bytes for 5 characters or 2bytes for an integer?

Comment: you could try and see :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`TextBox.Text` keeps the text as a simple string, it doesn't care about the real "meaning" of the string.

Then, if you want to have your number back, you need to parse the string, hence neither implicit  nor explicit cast to int is allowed (or better, it will throw an exception if you do it...).

About the size, that text is stored as an UNICODE (UTF-16) string, hence from 2 to 4 bytes per character (depending on the character).

You can easily measure the size (just the size of the string, without the overhead due to reference size etc.) using the following code:

```
int numBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(stringToMeasure);
```

To find more info about strings, unicode and encodings have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) or [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/unicode.html) .

Comment: SO, in this scenario, it will still take 5bytes of memory space, and store the value as a string. Well, then, turns out someone owes me a beer! :)

Comment: @jitendra garg: For sure you have won the beer, but don't be sure about the string size, use `int numBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(stringToMeasure)` to measure the actual size (in fact "12345" is 10 bytes, not 5 ).

Comment: @jitendra, @digEmAll: And don't forget that a `string` object will have additional overhead too. (I can't remember exactly how much, but I think it's roughly 20 bytes on top of the 2-bytes-per-character.)

Comment: @LukeH: good point, I forgot to mention it. For example there's the size of the reference address...

Answer (score 6):

your friend is wrong, it will make the compiler unhappy, the compiler won't even convert it automatically for you. Text property of a TextBox is of type string. check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you know you will only use numerical values, try using a [NumericUpDown control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx).
You could then get/set the numerical value (decimal) by using the `Value` property.

> A **NumericUpDown** control contains a single numeric value that can be incremented or decremented by clicking the up or down buttons of the control. The user can also enter in a value, unless the ReadOnly property is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

As to your question of other languages; if 'option strict' is not enabled, VB.NET will allow this. It will also allow this assignment if the input is not entirely numeric however, resulting in a runtime exception.

Comment: So, basically he is right, only thing, he got language name wrong. Lol.

Comment: Correct, in fact VB.net is not as strongly typed as C#, is more a Do-What-I-Mean language while C# is a Do-What-I-Say language